# Issue with Panorama Background Image Fade-In Animation?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, panorama-control

Hi I was using the sample found [here](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/11/wp7-panorama-smooth-background-changing/) for fading in a background image. Everything is working fine its just that before the fade in animation starts the image shows briefly then the animation starts.

> No Background => Full Image => Image Disappears => Animation Starts =>
>   Full Image

Note I did add the exact same code as him but I still get this result. I did notice that his sample was written for WP7 7.0 which I'm guessing is the reason it's not loading exactly like the example he provided.

Has anyone found a workaround for this?

Comment: Provided sample works for me as on the Jeff's video

Comment: @Ku6opr Until you update the project to WP7 7.1. After that there is a noticeable jump in the way the image loads on the bing page. I have confirmed that this ONLY happens on the bing page. The picture loading page from local storage works perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well even though it takes about a second and a half extra to load, I finally got it to stop blinking. Basically I would save the file to isolated storage, and then load the file from isolated storage instead of loading the image directly to the background after it finished downloading.

I got the idea based on the fact that the sample of loading the background using a local image worked perfectly.

Like I said it takes a little longer to download because of the saving and loading from isolated storage, but it works well.

Answer (score 1):

Make your background initially hidden in xaml or by code in page constructor. Animation starts after page loaded, so background is shown from application start to `Loaded` event

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. I'm pretty sure thought thats it's not happening in the loaded event. The page is completely loaded before I make a call to a feed that supplies the image. After the image is recieved I set it to the source like he mentioned but for someone reason the image shows, disappears, and then its starts like it's supposed to. I know its not alot to work off. Any more ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I bet you have opacity for image set to 1, and when it's loaded then you start showing it - resulting in bizarre flickering. Set opacity to 0 in xaml and then run your Storyboard (that animates opacity from 0 to 1).

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking! I'm just not sure where to change it. I tried doing it on the page where the panorama is but that didn't work. There is a page called Generic.xaml where it looks like the storyboard and style for the background resides in. I haven't been able to modify it correctly though. Have you downloaded the sample yet?